# iOS Change Chartboost delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, chartboost

How do I change the Chartboost delegate. It appears it can only be set once, at init. What if I want to change it after init? Do I just init again?

```
[Chartboost startWithAppId:@"APP_ID"
              appSignature:@"APP_SIGN"
                  delegate:myDelegate];
```

Comment: Can't you just assign a new value to the `Chartboost` object `delegate` property?

Comment: There's no such property exposed, as far as I can see

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation for the class on their site, so it seems you will need to allocate a new instance if you want to change the delegate, or you could create a singleton to be your delegate and have it proxy delegate methods out to the class instance that you wanted to be the actual delegate

Comment: Yes, both those options work. I am now just calling startWithAppId() again as needed, and according to Chartboost support, this does not have any adverse effects. This is less coding, but its not as future-proof as having a singleton with proxies. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call with StartWithAppId() as needed, and according to Chartboost support, this does not have adverse effects (at least in Chartboost v5.1.3). Creating a singleton to serve as the delegate and having that proxy the listener methods is a good option also.

Answer (score 0):

You can now call `Chartboost.setDelegate(self)`